# Released energy during fusion reaction

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, binding-energy

[Click to view the video at required time](https://youtu.be/jk6Hm1QoDYY?t=363)

According to the video in the link above 
the binding energy for deuterium is about 2 MeV and the binding energy for tritium is about 8 MeV so the total for the input items is 10 MeV the binding energy for helium is 28 MeV
I am confused by this part if the resulting binding energy is higher that means the extra energy is being taken not generated Can you please explain how come 18 MeV is release , I thought it's needed not released.

Comment: Sounds like D-T fusion. Yes, the final state of an alpha particle and a free neutron has more binding energy (is more stable than) a deuteron and a triton. What do you not understand about the energy?

Comment: @JonCuster My confusion arises from the fact that the extra 18MeV should be supplied to the reaction not released by the reaction

Comment: No, the final state is lower energy.

Comment: Google 'AME2016 atomic mass evaluation' to compare the relative mass (or mass excess energy) for the products and reactants.